# Caching API requests with JWT auth

Tags: php, nginx, caching, jwt, varnish

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to cache requests that require JWT auth and checking token contents.

Current setup:

- PHP API
- Nginx serving requests

Software I have been exploring:

- Nginx
- Varnish

Token contents:

- sub
- iss... (regular JWT contents)
- userGroupID

I have some shared content for users and some is personal. So I would like to be able to cache requests to some of the endpoints. Without even calling PHP, when data is available in the cache.

Let's say we have user groups and groups own cars. I would like to be able to authenticate and cache request to following endpoint:

```
https://myapi.example.com/groups/{groupID}/cars
```

To authenticate this request caching software would have to be able to compare the {groupID} to the groupID that is in the token. But afaik Varnish can only validate token, but can it check that token groupID matches the groupID in the URL?

Nginx has some JWT capabilities, but could not find anything here to achieve that:
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_jwt_module.html

Is there any other software that could achive this? Right now I am considering going back to caching stuff in PHP. Checking tokens there and using memcached or something else to cache data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster , a cache proxy server based on HAProxy

**1. Download and build, you will need lua**

```
wget https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster/releases/download/v1.8.8.2/nuster-1.8.8.2.tar.gz

make TARGET=linux2628 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 LUA_LIB=/opt/lua-5.3.1/lib LUA_INC=/opt/lua-5.3.1/include
```

**2. create lua scripts: base64.lua, json.lua, jwt_group_match.lua**

base64.lua

```
-- base64 FROM http://lua-users.org/wiki/BaseSixtyFour

local b='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'

base64 = {}

function base64.dec(data)
    data = string.gsub(data, '[^'..b..'=]', '')
    return (data:gsub('.', function(x)
        if (x == '=') then return '' end
        local r,f='',(b:find(x)-1)
        for i=6,1,-1 do r=r..(f%2^i-f%2^(i-1)>0 and '1' or '0') end
        return r;
    end):gsub('%d%d%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?', function(x)
        if (#x ~= 8) then return '' end
        local c=0
        for i=1,8 do c=c+(x:sub(i,i)=='1' and 2^(8-i) or 0) end
        return string.char(c)
    end))
end

return base64
```

json.lua

```
-- json FROM https://gist.github.com/tylerneylon/59f4bcf316be525b30ab
json = {}


function kind_of(obj)
  if type(obj) ~= 'table' then return type(obj) end
  local i = 1
  for _ in pairs(obj) do
    if obj[i] ~= nil then i = i + 1 else return 'table' end
  end
  if i == 1 then return 'table' else return 'array' end
end

function escape_str(s)
  local in_char  = {'\\', '"', '/', '\b', '\f', '\n', '\r', '\t'}
  local out_char = {'\\', '"', '/',  'b',  'f',  'n',  'r',  't'}
  for i, c in ipairs(in_char) do
    s = s:gsub(c, '\\' .. out_char[i])
  end
  return s
end

function skip_delim(str, pos, delim, err_if_missing)
  pos = pos + #str:match('^%s*', pos)
  if str:sub(pos, pos) ~= delim then
    if err_if_missing then
      error('Expected ' .. delim .. ' near position ' .. pos)
    end
    return pos, false
  end
  return pos + 1, true
end

function parse_str_val(str, pos, val)
  val = val or ''
  local early_end_error = 'End of input found while parsing string.'
  if pos > #str then error(early_end_error) end
  local c = str:sub(pos, pos)
  if c == '"'  then return val, pos + 1 end
  if c ~= '\\' then return parse_str_val(str, pos + 1, val .. c) end
  -- We must have a \ character.
  local esc_map = {b = '\b', f = '\f', n = '\n', r = '\r', t = '\t'}
  local nextc = str:sub(pos + 1, pos + 1)
  if not nextc then error(early_end_error) end
  return parse_str_val(str, pos + 2, val .. (esc_map[nextc] or nextc))
end

function parse_num_val(str, pos)
  local num_str = str:match('^-?%d+%.?%d*[eE]?[+-]?%d*', pos)
  local val = tonumber(num_str)
  if not val then error('Error parsing number at position ' .. pos .. '.') end
  return val, pos + #num_str
end

json.null = {}  -- This is a one-off table to represent the null value.

function json.parse(str, pos, end_delim)
  pos = pos or 1
  if pos > #str then error('Reached unexpected end of input.') end
  local pos = pos + #str:match('^%s*', pos)  -- Skip whitespace.
  local first = str:sub(pos, pos)
  if first == '{' then  -- Parse an object.
    local obj, key, delim_found = {}, true, true
    pos = pos + 1
    while true do
      key, pos = json.parse(str, pos, '}')
      if key == nil then return obj, pos end
      if not delim_found then error('Comma missing between object items.') end
      pos = skip_delim(str, pos, ':', true)  -- true -> error if missing.
      obj[key], pos = json.parse(str, pos)
      pos, delim_found = skip_delim(str, pos, ',')
    end
  elseif first == '[' then  -- Parse an array.
    local arr, val, delim_found = {}, true, true
    pos = pos + 1
    while true do
      val, pos = json.parse(str, pos, ']')
      if val == nil then return arr, pos end
      if not delim_found then error('Comma missing between array items.') end
      arr[#arr + 1] = val
      pos, delim_found = skip_delim(str, pos, ',')
    end
  elseif first == '"' then  -- Parse a string.
    return parse_str_val(str, pos + 1)
  elseif first == '-' or first:match('%d') then  -- Parse a number.
    return parse_num_val(str, pos)
  elseif first == end_delim then  -- End of an object or array.
    return nil, pos + 1
  else  -- Parse true, false, or null.
    local literals = {['true'] = true, ['false'] = false, ['null'] = json.null}
    for lit_str, lit_val in pairs(literals) do
      local lit_end = pos + #lit_str - 1
      if str:sub(pos, lit_end) == lit_str then return lit_val, lit_end + 1 end
    end
    local pos_info_str = 'position ' .. pos .. ': ' .. str:sub(pos, pos + 10)
    error('Invalid json syntax starting at ' .. pos_info_str)
  end
end

return json
```

jwt_group_match.lua

```
base64 = require("base64")
json = require("json")

function jwt_group_match(txn)

      local hdr = txn.http:req_get_headers()
      local jwt = hdr["jwt"]
      if jwt == nil then
        return false
      end

      _, payload, _ = jwt[0]:match"([^.]*)%.([^.]*)%.(.*)"
      if payload == nil then
        return false
      end

      local payload_dec = base64.dec(payload)
      local payload_json = json.parse(payload_dec)

      if txn.sf:path() == "/group/" ..  payload_json["userGroupID"] .. "/cars" then
        return true
      end
      return false
end

core.register_fetches("jwt_group_match", jwt_group_match)
```

**3. create conf, say, nuster.conf**

```
global
    nuster cache on dict-size 1m data-size 100m
    debug
    lua-load jwt_group_match.lua

frontend web1
    bind *:8080
    mode http

    default_backend app1

backend app1
    mode http
    http-request set-var(req.jwt_group_match) lua.jwt_group_match

    nuster cache on
    nuster rule group if { var(req.jwt_group_match) -m bool }


    server s1 127.0.0.1:8000
    server s2 127.0.0.1:8001
```

**3. start nuster**

```
./haproxy -f nuster.conf
```

**TEST**

```
payload: {
  "iss": "iss",
  "sub": "sub",
  "userGroupID": "nuster"
}

curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/group/nuster/cars --header "jwt: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJpc3MiLCJzdWIiOiJzdWIiLCJ1c2VyR3JvdXBJRCI6Im51c3RlciJ9.hPpqQS0d4T2BQP90ZDcgxnqJ0AHmwWFqZvdxu65X3FM"
```

First run

```
[CACHE] To create
```

Second run

```
[CACHE] Hit
```

For the Auth part, you can use https://github.com/SkyLothar/lua-resty-jwt